# JQuery chained selects implementation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a newbie as far as JQuery, AJAX & PHP are concerned and I am trying to build a form with chained selects that will provide initial data for a new mysql record.
I have downloaded the JQuery chained select remote plugin and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the data returned for the second select dropdown. The first dropdown is populated using another function and when the user selects a value from this dropdown, I want that value to be used as the search string for the second dropdown.
**The code snippet for the main form is:**

```
<?php

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.chained.remote.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#series').remoteChained("#series", "../models/json.php");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr> 
<th>Season:</th>
<td><select name="season" id="mark">
<option value="">Select Season...</option>
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($showseason)){  // obtain seasons from getseason() function
?>
<option value="<?php echo $showseason[$i]; ?>">
<?php echo $showseason[$i]; ?> </option>
<?php 
$i++;
} ?> 
</select></td>
<th>Competition:</th><td><select name="competition" id="series">
<option value="">Competition type...</option>
</select></td>
```

The following is the code for the Mysql select (json.php)

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db_connect.php';

try
{
    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sideid, competition FROM pennantsides");
    $result->execute();

    echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    }
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $output = 'Error selecting records - Please contact your Site Administrator';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/views/output.html.php';
    exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it $('#mark').remoteChained("#series", "../models/json.php"); you're trying to do ?

Also, what's the content of the json file when you launch it on your browser (or via whatever GET method you use) ?